# Parallelize Monte Carlo Integration

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, montecarlo

I would like to generate 1 billion random points from a probability distribution and evaluate functions using these points to calculate a Monte Carlo integral. The problem is I am using MATLAB and have little knowledge of other programming languages. MATLAB is of course very slow and I have discussed the possibility of parallelizing the integration by calculating the values for 100 million points in 10 different processes. Is this a possible approach? If so, what is the best way to implement it?

The current approach is as follows:

For i:N
Generate random number from distribution
Evaluate function 
Add function evaluation to temporary variable
end

Divide the temporary variable by N and thus the integral has been approximated.

The function being evaluated is as follows:
0 if the generated point is less than  number B
the difference between the point and B if the generated point is larger than or equal to B.

Using @Arpi's approach a parfor loop would be used instead.

Comment: "Matlab is of course very slow", well it largely depends on the user ;). Anyway, the parallelization is certainly possible, take a look at [`parfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html?refresh=true). Also, I would reconsider your approach to calculate the integral, there are many techniques to reduce the computational burden, e.g. importance sampling. But the 'best' approach is problem dependent.

Comment: That is true, and with me as a user it is definitely slow ;) Thank you for the help with both parfor and reconsidering my approach @Arpi!

Comment: You might want to provide a description/equations/psuedocode/diagram of your functions.  There are many approaches to panellizing an algorithm, finding the right one depends on the nature of the algorithm. for example, if your function just does basic arithmetic then the bottleneck is probably memory access, not CPU time, which means there is little/no point in using multiple cores/hyper-threads.

Comment: @dan-man A psuedocode has been added as per your suggestion. If the bottleneck is memory access, are there any ways to open up the bottleneck?

Comment: @rickri - we need some more details about what's inside the simple function; "simple" means different things to different people, and I suspect that the answer to your question involves vectorizing that function, and evaluating in batches.

Comment: @dan-man That is very true, a description of the function being evaluated has been added.

Comment: @rickri - is that really it? You can solve that analytically

Comment: @dan-man the integral we are trying to solve contain the probability density function of the students t-distribution which makes is slightly more complicated. So the integral we are trying to solve is as follows:  int from -inf to inf of h(x)*f(x) dx   Where h(x) is the function described in the original post and f(x) is the probability density function of the students t-distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that this is **[much, much simpler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)** than first suggested.  One could solve the problem analytically, by consulting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Integral_of_Student.27s_probability_density_function_and_p-value). But - and I stress that this is really not the right approach - since this is a programming site, here is a program:

```
b = 0.3;
N = 1e9;
batch_size = 1e8;

total = 0;
for ii=1:(N/batch_size)
    total = sum(max(0,rand(batch_size,1)-b));
end
result = total/N;
```

This takes about 15s to run. Could possibly go faster if batch size is chosen better.

Note that the "distribution" here is uniform on the interval `[0, 1)`, which may not be what is wanted, but the approach can be extended to work with any distribution type (many of which are builtins in Matlab).

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: @rickri - this is a terrible way to solve your actual problem. At the very least you could use a fixed range of `x` values rather than picking them randomly. and really you should integrate analytically - see [wkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Integral_of_Student.27s_probability_density_function_and_p-value).  You have fallen for the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).